# Conditional Formatting using Date Comparison

Tags: vba, date, excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a conditional formatting rule in VBA that will change the cell background color only for the current date. I have a column of dates for the year. I am also using Office Excel 2010.

```
oSheet.Range(Cells(iStartRow, 1), Cells(iLastRow, 1)).FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=" & Cells.Address & "=" & Date
```

I am trying to identify the current cell's address, so that it can be compared against today's date. Remember that this formula will be checked against a column of different dates.

I can create the conditional formatting in Excel easy enough, but I'm trying to recreate this statement in VBA code.

When I create the Conditional formatting necessary for the Dates Occurring in Excel and then view the formula in VBA; here are the results:
`=FLOOR(A32,1)=TODAY()`

Comment: You should be able to pull the current cell via:  selection.address ... can you not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get you what you want:

```
oSheet.Range(Cells(iStartRow, 1), Cells(iLastRow, 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A" & iStartRow & "=TODAY()"
```

If you want to reference a specific cell for your date comparison use (for example C1):

```
oSheet.Range(Cells(iStartRow, 1), Cells(iLastRow, 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A" & iStartRow & "=$C$1"
```

Notice that in both examples there is a `$` before the `A` because it is a fixed column, but there is NO `$` before the row because the row (`iStartRow`) needs to be variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution fixed the problem and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that CF rule's code fits into the surrounding code but you would do better to explicitly define the extents of the `.Range` as belonging to the same parent worksheet.

```
with oSheet
    .Range(.Cells(iStartRow, 1), .Cells(iLastRow, 1)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A" & iStartRow & "=TODAY()"
end with
```

The prefix periods (e.g. *full stop* or .) tell `.Range(...` and `.Cells(...` that they belong to `oSheet`. Without them, your code may work or it may not. There have been several cases recently where a simple parent mis-definition (by relying on the *ActiveSheet*) broke otherwise good code.